# Xelatex fails, no pdf, empty log

Tags: xetex, texlive, texmaker, debian

I would like to compile a tex-file with XeLatex using Texmaker 4.5 on Debian 10. On a Windows machine with Miktex it works fine.
Running "XeLatex" in Texmaker on debian results in an empty log / no messages and no PDF.

Running XeLatex in the terminal gives the following:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex) restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./04_Architektur.tex
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 10 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script document class (article)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package scrlfile, 2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (loading files)

Copyright (C) Markus Kohm ))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize10pt.cloxelatex: ../../src/hb-object.hh:269: Type* hb_object_reference(Type*) [with Type = hb_unicode_funcs_t]: Assertion `hb_object_is_valid (obj)' failed.
Aborted
```

Except from the missing space in `.cloxelatex` I cannot find any hints for further investigation of the problem. Any advices?
Thanks you!

EDIT: Minimal example

```
\XeTeXinputencoding utf-8
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside,titlepage]{scrartcl}
%Packages
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} % more modern
\usepackage{geometry}
% more features for in text ref
\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref} 
\begin{document}
\section{Example}
Let's try to use Frutiger font here.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example? Are you sure you are on Debian 10 (buster)? TeXlive 2016 can be found in Debian 9 (stretch).

Comment: The command `cat /etc/issue`gives: `Debian GNU/Linux 10 \n \l`

Comment: @RalfStubner, do you have any ideas considering the minimal code example? What do you think about [this approach](https://www.kryger.de/TeX-Live-for-Debian/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, but to long for a comment ...

I have tested your code on three different systems:

- Debian 9 with TeX Live 2016/Debian
- Debian 10 with TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian
- Debian testing with TeX Live 2019/Debian

Your code works fine in all three settings.

Now you are using Debian 10 together with TeX Live 2016/Debian, which was part of Debian 9. This looks as if you made a partial upgrade to Debian 10 from Debian 9 but left TeX Live in its old state. Updating your system to a consistent Debian 10 state might help.

Comment: Now, I added the buster sources and installed Tex Live 2018. I still get the error `(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize10pt.cloxelatex: ../../src/hb-object.hh:269: Type* hb_object_reference(Type*) [with Type = hb_unicode_funcs_t]: Assertion `hb_object_is_valid (obj)' failed.
Aborted`. Any further recommendations?

Comment: @peng Please edit your question to include the output from that run.

Comment: First, I had just updated TexLive. After an update of the entire system (like you recommended) it works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your error, notice the header file `hb-object.hh`. If you search after it, you will find that it is related to the `harfbuzz` packages.

Anyway, the problem comes form the `libharfbuzz-icu0` package that must be upgrade at least to 2.6.4-1.